# Addition not happening in loops

Tags: python, loops

I am new to python so I know it is a basic question but if you look at the code, the addition is not happening in loop. Everytime the multiplication is done and answer is printed. Can you tell me what am I doing wrong. It should output 10000 for first time, 20000 for the next since `cr` would have 10000 from previous iteration saved, right? It's kind of implementing summation and product together.

```
import math


#running cost
def RunningCostofVNF(cm, qm):
    cm = 5000
    qm = 2
    datacenters = [1,2]
    numberofVNFs = [1,2]

    for i in datacenters:
        for m in numberofVNFs:
            cr = cm * qm
            #cr = cr+cr
            print cr
    return    
#        print cr
 #   print cr
  #  return cr

RunningCostofVNF(1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your output as text in the question.

Comment: Please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This line `cr = cm * qm` is an *assignment* statement. Each time through the loop, the code calculates *a fresh value* (which is always `10000`) and assigns it to `cr`, throwing away the previous value. It does have `10000` from the previous iteration as you expect, but only up to the point where you assign it afresh.

If you want to accumulate the calculated value in `cr` then you need to change the code so that it doesn't compute it afresh every time, but instead accumulates a value every time through the loop:

```
cr = 0
for i in datacenters:
    for m in numberofVNFs:
        cr += cm * qm
        print cr
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have is it basically runs through the double for loops running the same multiplication each time (cm * qm) and overwriting the value of cr each time with the result.

If you want the value of cr to be saved from the previous iteration then what you need is to store it as an initial variable then increment it on each loop iteration. Changing the code to something similar to below would achieve this:

```html
cr = 0
for i in datacenters:
    for m in numberofVNFs:
        cr += cm * qm
        #cr = cr+cr
        print cr
return
```

Answer (score 0):

cr always 5000 times 2 ( cm*qm)
i guess it should be like i*m*qm or other else

Answer (score 0):

**For you ref:-**

```
cr = 0
for i in datacenters:
    for m in numberofVNFs:
        value = cm * qm
        cr +=value 
        print (cr)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have to initialise the 'cr' variable with the zero and use the previous iteration value of 'cr' in the new iteration so you can get the correct answer.

I am also attach the output of the code .

```
import math

#running cost
def RunningCostofVNF(cm, qm):
    cm = 5000
    qm = 2
    cr = 0
    datacenters = [1,2]
    numberofVNFs = [1,2]

    for i in datacenters:
        for m in numberofVNFs:
            cr =cr + cm * qm
            #cr = cr+cr
            print(cr)
    return    
#        print cr
 #   print cr
  #  return cr

RunningCostofVNF(1,1)
```

[image]